# Arbitrary path length query in SPARQL

Tags: neo4j, rdf, sparql

Is it possible to do arbitrary length of path queries in SPARQL. Lets say i have neo4j store which has a graph that only represents PARENT_OF relationships (consider a family tree for example). A cypher query to get all ancestors of a person would look like

```
start n (some node from index query) match n<-[:PARENT_OF*]-k return k
```

How would this query look like in SPARQL if this neo store were to be represented as a RDF based triple store. Is this even possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have data like this:

```
@prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22210295/1281433/> .

:a :parentOf :b .
:b :parentOf :c .
:c :parentOf :d .
```

then you can use a query like this, using SPARQL 1.1's [property paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths):

```
prefix : <http://stackoverflow.com/q/22210295/1281433/>

select ?ancestor ?descendent where {
  ?ancestor :parentOf+ ?descendent
}
```

to get results like this:

```
-------------------------
| ancestor | descendent |
=========================
| :a       | :b         |
| :a       | :c         |
| :a       | :d         |
| :b       | :c         |
| :b       | :d         |
| :c       | :d         |
-------------------------
```

Note that using `*` permits *zero* occurrences of the relation, and relates each node to itself.  If you want each thing to be an ancestor of itself, then you could replace `+` with `*` in my query.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the computational cost of this operation . I guess it will depend upon the triple store implementation. For popular implementations like allegro graph db is the performance comparable with neo4j or titan.

Comment: SPARQL doesn't define a particular execution model, so it's not really easy to say how computationally expensive it is.  It really depends on the implementation.  If you're interested in performance for some particular implementations, I think you'd have to test it yourself, or see whether anyone's compared them and published the results.